# Implementar un ciclo for en codigo dentro de mi código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

busco implementar un cambio en mi código, solo necesito implementar en el ***código 1*** del ciclo for del ***código 2*** de manera correcta:

```
for (j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
      if (j !== i)
        acc[j].classList.remove('active');
        acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
}
```

#### Codigo 1:

```
// Acordión
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var e;
var panel = document.querySelector('.panel');
var i;
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (e = 0; e < acc.length; e++) {
  acc[e].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    // for() {

    // }
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

#### Codigo 2:

```
var panelDOM = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

// Abrir acordión desde la navegación
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  a[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    acc[i].classList.toggle('active');
    for (j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
      if (j !== i)
        acc[j].classList.remove('active');
        acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    if (panelDOM[i].style.maxHeight) {
      panelDOM[i].style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panelDOM[i].style.maxHeight = panelDOM[i].scrollHeight + "px";
    }
    
  });
```

}

Comment: Y en este caso, que es lo que no funciona?, te refieres a que quieres optimizar tu codigo quizas porque ya funciona?

Comment: Bien, Hernando... Y tu pregunta es..?

Comment: Ya funciona, solo quiero hacer una ligera optimización.